# Implementing 5-variable function using multiplexers

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

If I have a 5-variable function (below) and I want to implement it using a multiplexer, how would I do that (using the minimum possible multiplexer):

```
f(A,B,C,D,E) = A + C'D + BD' + B'D + B'CE
```

This is homework, so don't provide a solution, just a guidance of how that works.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

5 variables means a 2**5 (32) input multiplexer, with inputs 0 through 31. Convert the terms into binary numbers and hold the corresponding inputs high. For `B'CE` we have:

```
A B C D E
X 0 1 X 1
```

This gives us 4 numbers, since we have 2 don't cares. The four numbers are:

```
00101 = 5
00111 = 7
10101 = 21
10111 = 23
```

Hold inputs 5, 7, 21, and 23 high.

Repeat for the rest of the terms.

Comment: You do that with the rest of the terms, pull the unused ones low, and wire A, B, C, D, and E to CS4, CS3, CS2, CS1, and CS0.

Comment: Once you find all the combinations, would you just put a 1 next to the corresponding input, and a 0 otherwise?

Comment: @styfle: If the inputs are active-high, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you explicitly mention

> using the minimum possible multiplexer

there's another way of doing it in which you only need a 2^(n-1) input multiplexer to implement a n input function (so, in your case, a MUX with 2^4 inputs and 4 select inputs would suffice). The idea is to use the first n-1 inputs of the truth table as select inputs for the MUX while the remaining one is connected to the data inputs as appropriate to give the desired result.

Since I can't post images yet, see this for a concrete example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8osbd8gtwhtfor/n-1inputmux.png

Or for how to implement simple logic gates with MUXes: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7cqbodha7lcoi9y/n-1inputmuxbasics.png

---

Sources:

http:// sifaka.uwaterloo.ca/~akenning/courses/ece124/

http:// 6004.mit.edu/

(I can't post more than two real links...)

Comment: Could you update the inactive links?

Answer (score 0):

The answers passed by Fanhoso and Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams are outdated or totally useless.

1. Count the frequency of the variables:

f(A,B,C,D,E) = A + C'D + BD' + B'D + B'CE

```
A: 1x;
B: 3x;
C: 2x;
D: 3x;
E: 1x;
```

The variables that appear the most, will become selector inputs, as this way they're used in the most efficient way (otherwise, the amount of necessary gates would increase). So in this case it'll be AE|BCD (where BCD form SELECTOR INPUTS).

2. For this and next steps, we need to know what minterms are included, so you should pass canonical sum of minterms. I figured out that your function looks as follows:

f(A,B,C,D,E) = Σ{ 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 }

Sort the minterms (in binary form), in the new variables order:

```
         ABCDE -> AE|BCD|
    (2)  00010 -> 00|001|
    (3)  00011 -> 01|001|
    (5)  00101 -> 01|010|
      .
      .
      .
```

3. Still, we don't know in what groups the desired signals will appear, so we need to group them once again, according to the same signals in the selector inputs line.

For example 001 on the selector inputs line transfers to input number 1 on the data input line. From 00|001 (2), it's possible to obtain other numbers i.e. 01|001 (3).

```
             ABCDE -> AE|BCD|
input data no 1:
        (2)  00010 -> 00|001|
        (3)  00011 -> 01|001|
         .
         .
input data no 2:
        (5)  00101 -> 01|010|
          .
          .
          .
```

4. The last thing before starting to draw a scheme, is to define how to connect signals AE with data input lines, meaning we need to know which gates are necessary to obtain desired outputs. In this example the input line 1 consists of:

   ```
    (2)  00010 -> 00|001|
    (3)  00011 -> 01|001|
   ```

So it's necessary to connect A' (E is "don't care") with the data input line number 1. Of course, the combination in your case will be totally different, once you group properly all the minterms.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer by [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129282/17627866) is wrong because it requires a 32x1 MUX when a 4x1 MUX suffices.

The algorithm to implement a 5-variable function using MUX is similar to the [algorithm for a 4-variable function](https://youtu.be/vOFeSu6Zr94):

- Draw the truth table for the function.
- From the truth table, draw a Karnaugh map.
- Choose a multiplexer with n inputs where n is the number of rows in the kmap. MUX uses some of the variables as select lines.
- Minimize the k-map by making groupings only row-wise (different from the traditional way).
- Implement circuit using equations derived from k-map

## Truth table

The truth table for `f = (a ∨ ((¬c ∧ d) ∨ ((b ∧ ¬d) ∨ ((¬b ∧ d) ∨ (¬b ∧ (c ∧ e))))))`:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f
F   F   F   F   F   F
F   F   F   F   T   F
F   F   F   T   F   T
F   F   F   T   T   T
F   F   T   F   F   F
F   F   T   F   T   T
F   F   T   T   F   T
F   F   T   T   T   T
F   T   F   F   F   T
F   T   F   F   T   T
F   T   F   T   F   T
F   T   F   T   T   T
F   T   T   F   F   T
F   T   T   F   T   T
F   T   T   T   F   F
F   T   T   T   T   F
T   F   F   F   F   T
T   F   F   F   T   T
T   F   F   T   F   T
T   F   F   T   T   T
T   F   T   F   F   T
T   F   T   F   T   T
T   F   T   T   F   T
T   F   T   T   T   T
T   T   F   F   F   T
T   T   F   F   T   T
T   T   F   T   F   T
T   T   F   T   T   T
T   T   T   F   F   T
T   T   T   F   T   T
T   T   T   T   F   T
T   T   T   T   T   T
```

`F` is false for rows 0, 1, 4, 14, 15.

You can use a truth table generator like this [one](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/) to verify that the truth table is correct.

## K-map

[image]

## Choosing multiplexer

A 4x1 MUX is required. The select lines will be `a` and `b`. The truth table for the 4x1 MUX is as follows:

```
a b f
0 0 f0(c, d, e)
0 1 f1(c, d, e)
1 0 f2(c, d, e)
1 1 f3(c, d, e)
```

We need to express the functions `f0`, `f1`, `f2`, `f3` in terms of `c`, `d`, `e`. This is done using k-map groupings (in the next section).

## Minimizing k-map

The groupings are done only row-wise.

[image]

`f0 = ((¬a ∧ (¬b ∧ d)) ∨ (¬a ∧ (¬b ∧ (c ∧ e))))`

`f1 = ((¬a ∧ (b ∧ ¬d)) ∨ (¬a ∧ (b ∧ ¬c)))`

`f2 = (a ∧ ¬b)`

`f3 = (a ∧ b)`

## Circuit

### Subcircuits

#### `f0`

[image]

#### `f1`

[image]

#### `f2`

[image]

#### `f3`

[image]

### Main circuit

[image]

### Truth table verification

The truth table of the final circuit as computed by [logisim](https://sourceforge.net/projects/circuit/) (a circuit simulator) is:

[image]

This is exactly the same as the truth table that we found earlier. This means that the circuit is correct.

The logisim circuit can be accessed [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Gd5vnZyvGK3Rru6T8fPwfaC3Gt7PgKt/view?usp=sharing).